# Prove $m_{1,0}\ge n-1$ in one dimensional symmetric random walk

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, random-walk

Let $m_{1,0}$ denotes the expected time of transitions starting from state $1$, until a transition into state $0$ occurs, in one dimensional symmetric random walk, with infinite countable states i.e. state $0,\pm 1, \pm2,...$

In the one dimensional symmetric random walk, it has been proven that: the mean number of transitions to go from state $1$ to either $0$ or $n$ is $n − 1$

From state $1$ to state $n$, there are at least $n-1$ transitions and
$n-1 = m_{1,0}$*Pr{getting to $0$}+$m_{1,n}$*Pr{getting to $n$}

so I think is should be $m_{1,0}\le n-1$ because the mean number is $n-1$.

But in the book: *Introduction to Probability Models (Sheldon M. Ross)* $~~$page 218, there is:

> The classical example of a null recurrent Markov chain is the one dimensional
> symmetric random walk of Example 4.18. One way to show it is null recurrent is to argue that the mean time to return to a state is infinite. 
> (For another
> argument, see Exercise 39.) To show this, let $m_{i,j}$ denote the mean number of
> transitions, starting in state i, until a transition into state j occurs.
> Now, in Example 3.16, it was shown that the mean number of transitions to go from state
> 1 to either $0$ or $n$ is $n-1$, implying that
> $m_{1,0}\ge n-1$

So I wonder which one is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book is correct. Getting to $0$ takes at least as long as getting to either $0$ or $n$, so the expected time to get from $1$ to $0$ is at least the expected time to get from $1$ to either $0$ or $n$.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but I wonder why "Getting to 0 takes at least as long as getting to either 0 or n". In my opinion, "Getting to 0" belongs to  "getting to either 0 or n", and expected number of getting to 0 or n = n-1 = $m_{1,0}$*Pr{getting to 0} + $m_{1,n}$*Pr{getting to n}, and $m_{1,n}\ge n-1$, in consequence  $m_{1,0}\le n-1$

Comment: @Gangmen: No. The event "$0$ was reached" is a subset of the event "($0$ was reached) or ($n$ was reached)"; a subset has at most the probability of its superset; and if $A(t)$ is a subset of $B(t)$ for all $t$, then the expected time until $A(t)$ occurs is at least the expected time until $B(t)$ occurs. I don't understand your equation; it's not clear what "Pr{getting to 0}" and "Pr{getting to n}" are supposed to mean – in a symmetric walk, these would both be $1$.

Comment: I suspect you're confusing some of these quantities with their conditional versions – perhaps you were thinking of 
$$
\mathsf E(\text{time to reach $0$ or $n$})=\mathsf E(\text{time to reach $0\mid0$ is reached before $n$})\mathsf P(\text{$0$ is reached before $n$})+\mathsf E(\text{time to reach $n\mid n$ is reached before $0$ })\mathsf P(\text{$n$ is reached before $0$})\;.
$$

But that's a completely different equation.

Comment: I am a little bit  confused, so $m_{1,0}\ne \mathsf E(\text{time to reach $0\mid0$ is reached before $n$})$? If so, what is the expectation expression of $m_{1,0}$

Comment: @Gangmen: I don't have the book, I can only go by what you wrote: "$m_{1,0}$ denotes the expected time of transitions starting from state $1$ to state $0$ in one dimensional symmetric random walk with $n+1$ states form state $0$ to state $n$". You didn't say what happens at the endpoints. If the walk is absorbed at the endpoints, i.e. ends when it reaches an endpoint, then $m_{1,0}$ is infinite, since the walk may never reach $0$. If the walk is reflected at the endpoints, $m_{1,0}$ is just the usual expectation, which is greater than the one conditioned on $0$ being reached before $n$.

Comment: Sorry about that, I think I mistaken the meaning of  $m_{1,0}$, and it should be the expected time of transitions starting from state $1$, until a transition into state $0$ occurs, in one dimensional symmetric random walk, with infinite countable states i.e. state $0,\pm 1, \pm2,... $. In short, it should be infinite countable states instead of $n+1$ states

Comment: @Gangmen: I see. Then it all makes sense. They want to show that that expectation is infinite, and they do so by showing that it's greater than any $n\in\mathbb N$. (By the way, this shows that it's best to quote the definitions verbatim from the book rather than paraphrasing them, because it's always possible that you misunderstood them.)

Comment: Thank you so much and I think I get it